# Interactive video website (HTML5, Flash)

Tags: html, flash, video, html5-video, flash-video

How do you create video like this: http://www.kasesesmu.lv/lv/ ?

Do you know any similar websites, maybe some tutorials on this?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [H5P](https://h5p.org), which has a lot of interactive content types. One of them is Interactive Video, which can be seen here:

https://h5p.org/interactive-video